# Start and stop TimerTask in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, timertask

I have a dynamic viewpager which shows image, youtube video and soundcloud audio. I added timertask to auto-change viewpager pages every 3 seconds. I want to stop this auto-change when a youtube video is playing or a soundcloud audio is playing and then resume it when the playing stops. For that I made two methods `starttime()` and `stoptime()`. But I'm getting **RuntimeException** when I click the button to play youtube video inside adapter (for viewpager).

```js
// Activity

public class Event_Details_Activity extends FragmentActivity implements RideRequestButtonCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
  GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult> {

 private static int currentPage = 0;
 private static int NUM_PAGES = 0;
 Handler myhandler;
 TimerTask timerTask;

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  try {
   pagerAdapter.displayYoutubeVideo.clearView();
   pagerAdapter.displayYoutubeVideo.freeMemory();
   pagerAdapter.displayYoutubeVideo.removeAllViews();
   pagerAdapter.displayYoutubeVideo.destroy();

   Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView")
     .getMethod("onPause", (Class[]) null)
     .invoke(pagerAdapter.displayYoutubeVideo, (Object[]) null);
   pagerAdapter.displayYoutubeVideo.onPause();

   if (handler!= null) {
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
   }

   stoptime();

  }catch (Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }

 @Override
 protected void onStop() {
  super.onStop();
  try {
   if(pagerAdapter.displayYoutubeVideo!=null){
    Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView")
      .getMethod("onPause", (Class[]) null)
      .invoke(pagerAdapter.displayYoutubeVideo, (Object[]) null);

   }


  } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
   cnfe.printStackTrace();
  } catch(NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
   nsme.printStackTrace();
  } catch(InvocationTargetException ite) {
   ite.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
   iae.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  if (pagerAdapter.mPlayer != null) {
   pagerAdapter.mPlayer.release();
   pagerAdapter.mPlayer = null;
  }
  try {
   //pagerAdapter.displayYoutubeVideo.onFinishTemporaryDetach();
  }catch (Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }


 }

 
 EventMoreDetails evDetails;
 
 
 static ViewPager myPager;
 
 ArrayList<ProdictDetailImageModel> algalary = new ArrayList<ProdictDetailImageModel>();
 
 static ProductDetailImagePagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
 
 LinearLayout llindicator;
 LinearLayout pbloaderll;

 ImageView ivrightarrow;
 ImageView ivleftarrow;
 TextView tvpagetext;

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onResume();

  starttime();

 }

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.event_details_activity);
  
  
  eventtitletv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eventtitletv);
  locationtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationtv);
  venuetv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.venuetv);
  datetv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.datetv);
  timetv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timetv);
  pricetv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pricetv);
  descriptiontv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descriptiontv);
  fbshareiv = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.fbshareiv);
  twittershareiv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.twittershareiv);
  yahooshareiv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yahooshareiv);
  nevigationll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.nevigationll);
  diariseiv = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.diariseiv);
  birthdaydescriptiontv  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.birthdaydescriptiontv);
  callpromterll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncallpromter);
  guestlistll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnguestlist);

  pbloaderll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pbloaderll);
  
  myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
  llindicator = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llindicator);
  
  tvpagetext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvpagetext);

 
  
  bookticketbt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bookticketbt);

  

  Event_Details_Activity_Static = this;

  sharell = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.sharell);

  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
  product_id = bundle.getString("product_id");

  pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);


  
  menull = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menull);
 


  ImageView menubutton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menubutton);
  ImageView chatAdminchiv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.chatAdminchiv);
  RideRequestButton blackButton = (RideRequestButton) findViewById(R.id.uber_button_white);
  chatAdminchiv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  blackButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  menubutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  ImageView youtubebutton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.youtubechiv);
  youtubebutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  




  
  myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    
    tvpagetext.setText(arg0+1 +" of "+  pagerAdapter.getCount());

    
    MyPagerPosition = arg0;
    
   }

   @Override
   public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
  });
  
  

  GeneralAsynctask gAsync = new GeneralAsynctask(
    Event_Details_Activity.this) {

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    try {
     
     JSONArray resultArray = jObj.getJSONArray("EventsList");
     for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject jinnerObj = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
      
      
      
      JSONArray galary = jinnerObj.getJSONArray("gallery");
      for (int j = 0; j < galary.length(); j++) {
       Log.d("IMAGE lINK",galary.getString(j));
       algalary.add(new ProdictDetailImageModel(galary.getString(j), ProdictDetailImageModel.TYPE_IMAGE));
      }
      
      //algalary.add(new ProdictDetailImageModel(jinnerObj.getString("video"), ProdictDetailImageModel.TYPE_VIDEO));
      //algalary.add(new ProdictDetailImageModel("http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+jinnerObj.getString("video")+"/0.jpg", ProdictDetailImageModel.TYPE_VIDEO));

      if(!jinnerObj.getString("video").isEmpty() && jinnerObj.getString("video")!=null){;

       algalary.add(new ProdictDetailImageModel(jinnerObj.getString("video"), ProdictDetailImageModel.TYPE_VIDEO));
      }

      if(!jinnerObj.getString("soundcloud").isEmpty() && jinnerObj.getString("soundcloud")!=null){

       ProdictDetailImageModel audio = new ProdictDetailImageModel(jinnerObj.getString("soundcloud_image"), ProdictDetailImageModel.TYPE_AUDUIO);
       audio.audio = jinnerObj.getString("soundcloud");

       algalary.add(audio);

      }





      if(algalary.size()>0){
          pagerAdapter = new ProductDetailImagePagerAdapter(Event_Details_Activity.this, algalary, pbloaderll);
       myPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
                      myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
       tvpagetext.setText(1 + " of " + pagerAdapter.getCount());
       
                      starttime();
      }
      
      Log.d("imagelength", algalary.size() +"");
      
      registerReceiver(pushreceiver, new IntentFilter("com.sam"));
  
 } // End of onCreate

 public void starttime(){

  Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();

  NUM_PAGES = algalary.size();

  handler = new Handler();
  final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
     currentPage = 0;
    }
    myPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
   }
  };


  timerTask = new TimerTask() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    handler.post(Update);
   }
  };


  swipeTimer.schedule(timerTask, 3000, 3000);

 }

 public void stoptime(){
  if(timerTask!=null){
   timerTask.cancel();
  }
 }
 
 private BroadcastReceiver pushreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
   if (extras != null) {
    String state = extras.getString("message");
    System.out.println("STATE"+" "+state);
    if(state.equals("start")){
     starttime();
    }else if(state.equals("stop")){
     stoptime();
    }
   }
  }
 };

 
 
 static int MyPagerPosition=0;
 public static Handler handler = new Handler();
 public static Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
             if( MyPagerPosition >= pagerAdapter.getCount()-1){
                 MyPagerPosition = 0;
             }else{
                 MyPagerPosition = MyPagerPosition+1;
             }
             myPager.setCurrentItem(MyPagerPosition, true);
             handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
     }
 };
 
 


}
```

```css
// ViewPager Adapter

public class ProductDetailImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
 private Activity activity;
 
 private LayoutInflater mInflater,mLayoutInflater;

 private ArrayList<ProdictDetailImageModel> ICONS;
 
 public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "AIzaSyDA3eXyi3tXfHkhiNSyFm11mp4s9f9nhnk";
 
 public static  String YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE = "v99W1n9BSlc";
 
 private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

 public static MediaPlayer mPlayer;

 public boolean isplayung = false;

 public boolean ispaused = false;

 AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> prepareMusicAsync;

 LinearLayout pbloaderll;

 ProgressDialog pdcms;

 String stream_url;

 public WebView displayYoutubeVideo;

  public ImageView ivaudio;

 public ProductDetailImagePagerAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<ProdictDetailImageModel> ICONS, LinearLayout pbloaderll) {
  this.activity = activity;
  this.ICONS = ICONS;
  mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  this.pbloaderll = pbloaderll;
  
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  return ICONS.size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object instantiateItem(View container, final int position) {




  
  View view = null;
  if(ICONS.get(position).type.equals(ProdictDetailImageModel.TYPE_IMAGE)){
   
   view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_detail_image_row, null);

   ImageView ivimage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivimage);

   

   String eventImageLink = ICONS.get(position).image;
  
   if (!eventImageLink.equals("")) {           
           try {
             String apiLink = eventImageLink;
             
          
          String encodedurl = "";
          encodedurl = apiLink.substring(0,apiLink.lastIndexOf('/'))+ "/"+ Uri.encode(apiLink.substring(
          apiLink.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
        Log.d("IMAGE LINK", "encodedurl:"+encodedurl);
     if (!apiLink.equals("") && apiLink != null) {
         Picasso.with(activity)
        .load(encodedurl) 
        .placeholder(R.drawable.listviewbg)

        .error(R.drawable.listviewbg)
        .into(ivimage); 
     }
     } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
  }else if(ICONS.get(position).type.equals(ProdictDetailImageModel.TYPE_VIDEO)){
   
   
   
   
   view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_detail_video_image_row, null);
   
   ImageView ivimage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivimage);
   ImageView play = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.play);

   

   String eventImageLink = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ICONS.get(position).image+"/0.jpg";
   
   if (!eventImageLink.equals("")) {           
           try {
             String apiLink = eventImageLink;
             
        
          String encodedurl = "";
          encodedurl = apiLink.substring(0,apiLink.lastIndexOf('/'))+ "/"+ Uri.encode(apiLink.substring(
          apiLink.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
        Log.d("IMAGE LINK", "encodedurl:"+encodedurl);
     if (!apiLink.equals("") && apiLink != null) {
         Picasso.with(activity)
        .load(encodedurl) // load: This path may be a remote URL,      
        .placeholder(R.drawable.listviewbg)

        .error(R.drawable.listviewbg)
        .into(ivimage); 
     }
     } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

   play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    
     Intent i = new Intent(activity, YoutubePlayerActivity.class);
     i.putExtra("youtubeid", YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE);
     activity.startActivity(i);


    }
   });
   
   YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE = ICONS.get(position).image;
   
  }else{
   view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_detail_audio_image_row, null);

   ImageView ivimage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivimage);
   ivaudio = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivaudio);

   

   String eventImageLink = ICONS.get(position).image;
    
   if (!eventImageLink.equals("")) {
    try {
     String apiLink = eventImageLink;

    
     String encodedurl = "";
     encodedurl = apiLink.substring(0,apiLink.lastIndexOf('/'))+ "/"+ Uri.encode(apiLink.substring(
       apiLink.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
     Log.d("IMAGE LINK", "encodedurl:"+encodedurl);
     if (!apiLink.equals("") && apiLink != null) {
      Picasso.with(activity)
        .load(encodedurl) 
        .placeholder(R.drawable.listviewbg)

        .error(R.drawable.listviewbg)
        .into(ivimage); 
     }
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

   ivaudio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     
     try {
      if (Event_Details_Activity.handler!= null) {
       Event_Details_Activity.handler.removeCallbacks(Event_Details_Activity.runnable);
      }
     }catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     Log.v("IS PLAYING  >", isplayung +"");

     if(!isplayung) {


      
      stream_url = replaceString(ICONS.get(position).audio);

      Log.e("stream_url","***"+stream_url);
      mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
      mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      try {

       Log.v("Stream Url  >", stream_url + "?client_id=fd557f1b3b255669587932f72b65f562");
       mPlayer.setDataSource(stream_url + "?client_id=fd557f1b3b255669587932f72b65f562");
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
       Toast.makeText(activity, "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } catch (SecurityException e) {
       Toast.makeText(activity, "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
       Toast.makeText(activity, "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
      commentpostActivity(pbloaderll);

      isplayung = true;
      ivaudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_pause);
     }else{
      if(mPlayer!=null && mPlayer.isPlaying() && !ispaused){
       mPlayer.pause();
       ispaused = true;
       ivaudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_play);

      }else if(mPlayer!=null && ispaused){
       mPlayer.start();
       ispaused = false;
       ivaudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_pause);
      }
      

     }




    }
   });
  }
  

  

  
 

  
 
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(view, 0);

  

  return view;
 }

 
 @Override
 public float getPageWidth(int position) {
  return(1f);
 }



 @Override
 public void destroyItem(View  arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
  ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
  
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
  return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
 }

 @Override
 public Parcelable saveState() {
  return null;
 }

 private static class ViewHolder {  
  RelativeLayout linearLayout;
  ImageView cover;
  TextView title;
  TextView pricetv;
  TextView destaince;;
 }

 public String replaceString(String rtstr) {

  rtstr = rtstr.replace("[", "");
  rtstr = rtstr.replace("{", "");
  rtstr = rtstr.replace("}", "");
  rtstr = rtstr.replace("\"", "");
  rtstr = rtstr.replace("\\/", "/");
  rtstr = rtstr.replace("]", "");
  rtstr = rtstr.replace(" ", "%20");

  return rtstr;

 }
 void commentpostActivity(final LinearLayout pbloaderll){

  prepareMusicAsync = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>( ){

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
    
    super.onPreExecute();
    

   }

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
   

    try {
     mPlayer.prepare();


    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
     Toast.makeText(activity, "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     Toast.makeText(activity, "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return null;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    mPlayer.start();
    pbloaderll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }

  };

  prepareMusicAsync.execute( );

 }
 Dialog youtubevideodialog; 
    private void showWaitingnooftickitsDialog() {
        try {
            youtubevideodialog = new Dialog(activity);
           
            youtubevideodialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            youtubevideodialog.setContentView(R.layout.product_detail_video_row);
            youtubevideodialog.setCancelable(true);

            youtubevideodialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
           

   YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView)youtubevideodialog.findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayer);

  


            youtubevideodialog.show();



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

```html
// LOGCAT

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.nits.londonclubnights, PID: 11899
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.nits.londonclubnights/com.nits.londonclubnights.YoutubePlayerActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.nits.application.AppApplication cannot be cast to com.nits.londonclubnights.Event_Details_Activity
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3028)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3063)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2418)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.nits.application.AppApplication cannot be cast to com.nits.londonclubnights.Event_Details_Activity
at com.nits.londonclubnights.YoutubePlayerActivity.onResume(YoutubePlayerActivity.java:110)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1280)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6096)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3011)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3063) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2418) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

```html
// YoutubeBaseActivity

public class YoutubePlayerActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{

public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "AIzaSyDA3eXyi3tXfHkhiNSyFm11mp4s9f9nhnk";
 
 // YouTube video id
 public static  String YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE = "v99W1n9BSlc";
 
 private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube_player);
  this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(true);
  
  YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayer);

  
  youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
  
  YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE = getIntent().getExtras().getString("youtubeid");
  Log.e("YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE",":"+YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE);

  try {

   if(Event_Details_Activity.pagerAdapter.mPlayer!=null && Event_Details_Activity.pagerAdapter.mPlayer.isPlaying() && !Event_Details_Activity.pagerAdapter.ispaused){
    Event_Details_Activity.pagerAdapter.mPlayer.pause();
    Event_Details_Activity.pagerAdapter.ispaused = true;
    Event_Details_Activity.pagerAdapter.ivaudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_play);

   }
   
  }catch (Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();

  Intent intent1 = new Intent("com.sam");
  intent1.putExtra("message", "stop");
  YoutubePlayerActivity.this.sendBroadcast(intent1);

 }

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();

  Intent intent2 = new Intent("com.sam");
  intent2.putExtra("message", "start");
  YoutubePlayerActivity.this.sendBroadcast(intent2);
 }
}
```

Comment: You are not allowed to cast Application Context to your activity..
((Event_Details_Activity)getApplicationContext()).starttime()-->this is wrong

Comment: Can you show me how to call the method?

Answer (score 0):

Do not call methods in `Event_Details_Activity` class from another activities.
Create a `BroadCastReciever` in `Event_Details_Activity` and in `onRecieve` method call `starttime()` and `stoptime()` methods.

So whenever you want to call `starttime()` and `stoptime()` from outside `Event_Details_Activity` simply send a broadcast.

**There are many other ways to do it. You can google it and opt for the best way.

Comment: I'm using some elements of `Event_Details_Activity` in my starttime() method. So I need to keep the methods in the same activity. Keeping that in mind, how to call these methods from BroadcastReceiver? @Chandrakanth

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer...create BroadcastReciever in the activity as inner calss...so you can call activity methods from inner class(BroadcastReciever).

Comment: Hi. I updated the latest code in which I used Broadcast receiver for calling the methods. But still I'm getting same error @Chandrakanth

Comment: Can you post your latest logcat and mention where exactly you are getting the exception

Comment: Done. Line 110 is the `onResume` method in YoutubePlayerActivity class.

Comment: in onResume() the code is clear...It will not give ClassCastException...Once cross check your code and logcat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121236/discussion-between-chandrakanth-and-somnath-pal).